# Plotting a histogram of 2D numpyArray of (latitude, latitude), in order to determine the proper values for DBSCAN

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I am trying to apply DBSCAN on a dataset of (Lan,Lat) .. The algorithm is very sensitive for the parameter; EPS & MinPts.

I would like to have a look through a Histogram over the data, to determine the proper values. Unfortunately, Matplotlib **Hist()** take only **1D array**.

Passing a 2D matrix as argument, **Hist()** treats each column as a separate input.

Scatter plot and histograms:

[image: Scatter Plot for Data]

[image: Historgram]

Does anyone has a way to solve this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the DBSCAN article, you only need the 4-nearest-neighbor distance for each object, not all pairwise distances. I.e., a 1 dimensional array.

Instead of doing a histogram, they *sort* the values, and try to choose a *knee* in this plot.

1. find the 4 nearest neighbor of each object
2. collect all 4NN distances in one array
3. sort this array in descending order
4. plot the resulting curve
5. look for a knee, often best at around 5%-10% of your x axis (so 95%-90% of objects are core points).

For details, see the original DBSCAN publication!

Comment: Thanks for reply .. I have already read the paper and I tried to apply the approach .. However, my data is very skewed, I can not find a knee .. Please find the image below ..

Comment: If you would update your question with the k-distance plot, that would be helpful. Also, the "knee" is usually not very obvious (no way to automatically detect it - it is a matter of *interpretation*). Zoom in on the relevant area - both the long tail and the outliers in the very beginning are useless.

Comment: P.S. Or you could use OPTICS clustering, which improves over DBSCAN by not needing the epsilon parameter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 100
arr = np.random.random((N, 2))
xedges = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
yedges = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
lat = arr[:, 0]
lng = arr[:, 1]
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(lat, lng, (xedges, yedges))
print(hist)
```

yields

```
[[ 0.  0.  5.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  3.  0.  0.  4.  0.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  3.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.  0.  3.  1.  2.  1.  1.  3.]
 [ 3.  0.  3.  2.  0.  1.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  3.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.  1.  0.  1.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  0.  2.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  2.  0.  0.]]
```

---

Or to visualize the histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(hist)
plt.show()
```

[image]